# Can fat be used as a sugar substitute?

Tags: fat, sugar-free

I'm not so concerned about obesity — I feel that's about portion control. Rather, I'm concerned about sugar being a carcinogen.

Comment: If you wanted to make this about cooking, rather than about diet, a question along the lines of "Can fat be used as a sugar substitute in this class of cake?" could be on topic (with the answer "no")

Answer (score 8):

We can't speak to health or medical issues on this site.  Beyond that, I don't see how fat can be used as a sugar substitute.  They are completely different ingredients that serve completely different purposes.